# googleapi_auth, how it really work?

Tags: google-api, dart

I'm playing with Google Drive's API and I would know if I need to do the code bellow each time I need to use the API:

```dart
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart" as gauth;
import "package:googleapis/drive/v2.dart" as drive;
...
  var clientid = new gauth.ClientId("xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", null);
  var scope = [drive.DriveApi.DriveScope];

  gauth.createImplicitBrowserFlow(clientid, scope).then((gauth.BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
    flow.clientViaUserConsent().then((gauth.AutoRefreshingAuthClient client) {
      var drive_api = new drive.DriveApi(client);
      // My code here.
      }).catchError((e) => print(e));
  });
...
```

Once client var generated, there is no way to recover it without to do these code lines each time?

Comment: Without nowing how the google auth api works - you should be able to reuse a session generated with oauth. In general OAuth should give you tokens or other data that you can save as persistent data. This should normally be possible and you should check the package if there's a possibility to save/read persistently stored sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally save the variable you called drive_api globally (in memory) and reuse it in my application (i.e. my webapp so yes it will run again when you reload the page). Some errors (I guess when the token needs to be refreshed, or if the permissions are revoked) might require you to re-run the whole flow. I think the trick is to run it "silently" after the page is loaded

```
flow.clientViaUserConsent(immediate: true)
```

by doing so, your "drive_api" variable will be loaded if the user already granted permission in previous sessions. For example I typically enable some buttons at this point

and if it fails (i sometimes add a "login button"), explicitly call (better do that on "on-click" to allow popup to appear)

```
flow.clientViaUserConsent()
```

Some doc for the immediate parameter:

```
/// If [immediate] is `true` there will be no user involvement. If the user
/// is either not logged in or has not already granted the application access,
/// a `UserConsentException` will be thrown.
///
/// If [immediate] is `false` the user might be asked to login (if he is not
/// already logged in) and might get asked to grant the application access
/// (if the application hasn't been granted access before).
```